# Magento2: How to show billing address at bottom of payment method instead of showing for each payment

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address, payment-step

I want to show billing addresses at last of payment step only 1 time instead of showing for each method. Now the billing addresses are in payment method container. I have checked there is code in form template of each payment method.

```
<div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
```

Which is used to show billing address. I have tried to put it on payment.html without $parent but its not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a configuration value for this under `Stores->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Checkout Options->Display Billing Address On`

Change the setting from `Payment Method` to `Payment Page`. The result will be:
[image: Payment Page]

Comment: Great Man! I was not aware of this setting and was trying to do same from code. You saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it through code.

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\payment.html

```
<li id="payment" role="presentation" class="checkout-payment-method col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-4 offset-lg-3 billing-sec" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div id="checkout-step-payment"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content"
     role="tabpanel"
     aria-hidden="false">
    <!-- ko if: (quoteIsVirtual) -->
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
    <form id="co-payment-form" class="form payments" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input data-bind='attr: {value: getFormKey()}' type="hidden" name="form_key"/>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Payment Information'"></span>
            </legend><br />
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('beforeMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-methods-list') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
                <!-- ko i18n: 'No Payment method available.'--><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

remove this KO code

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
   <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
 <!-- /ko -->
```

and place it after

```
<legend class="legend">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Payment Information'"></span>
            </legend><br />
```

so, you new code should be like this,

```
<li id="payment" role="presentation" class="checkout-payment-method col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-4 offset-lg-3 billing-sec" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div id="checkout-step-payment"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content"
     role="tabpanel"
     aria-hidden="false">
    <!-- ko if: (quoteIsVirtual) -->
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
    <form id="co-payment-form" class="form payments" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input data-bind='attr: {value: getFormKey()}' type="hidden" name="form_key"/>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Payment Information'"></span>
            </legend><br />
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('beforeMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-methods-list') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
                <!-- ko i18n: 'No Payment method available.'--><!-- /ko -->
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

deploy static content and 
Remove cache

Result: http://prntscr.com/nd1fs6